# Power analysis for multilevel model

Tags: statistical-significance, multilevel-analysis, statistical-power

Given a null finding (i.e. coefficient estimate is not statistically significant), how do you determine the statistical power of the study to reject the null? How large effects would have been detectable? How does the answer differ for independent variables that are measured on a higher level?

Here is my concrete case: 1578 cases clustered in 26 regions, binary response variable. Key independent variable measured on the regional level. Generalized linear mixed-effects model (`glmer` in R) with 6 control variables on the individual level and 3 control variables on the regional level.